# In Android, how to make Login button disable with respect to EditText?

Tags: button, android-edittext, android, android-button

If `EditText` is empty then Login `Button` has to be disabled. And if `EditText` has some texts then Login `Button` has to be enabled. Well you can see this method on Instagram Login.

Both fields are empty, Sign in `Button` is DISABLED.

[image]

Here Password field is empty, so still Sign in`Button` is DISABLED.

[image]

Here both Username and Password field is not empty, So Sign in`Button` is ENABLED.

[image]

how to achieve these steps??
here is my code and it doesn't work..

```
EditText et1,et2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_check);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = et2.getText().toString();

    if(s1.equals("")|| s2.equals("")){
        b.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        b.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try looking over TextUtils: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html - it has a feature "isEmpty" which might be handy here.

Comment: have you try this if(s1.length()==0|| s2.length()==0)?

Comment: check my answer if it works for you.

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj yes i have tried it.. And look at my accepted answer. its working :D

Comment: Hi can you update me the Button Style.XML with colour code or just color codes please.... I like your button style and color codes...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

heres what you are looking for :

```
private EditText et1,et2;
//  create a textWatcher member
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // check Fields For Empty Values
        checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
    }
};

void checkFieldsForEmptyValues(){
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = et2.getText().toString();

    if(s1.equals("")|| s2.equals("")){
        b.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        b.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_check);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    // set listeners
    et1.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

    // run once to disable if empty
    checkFieldsForEmptyValues(); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for you petey!! It worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: @SalutAmigo . perhaps you have a different issue.  Thanks for the unexplained down vote.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement [***TextWatcher***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on `EditText` to achieve the result.

```
EditText et1, et2;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    checkValidation();

    et1.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
}

private void checkValidation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText()))
            || (TextUtils.isEmpty(et2.getText())))
        b.setEnabled(false);
    else
        b.setEnabled(true);

}

TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        checkValidation();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to track user's action inside `EditText` using `TextWatcher` object:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                if (s.length() > 1)
                {
                    //enable button
                } else
                    //disable
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
EditText et1,et2;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_check);
  et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


  et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
                            String s2 = et2.getText().toString();

                             if(s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")){
                                   b.setEnabled(false);
                            } 
                            else if(!s1.equals("")&&s2.equals("")){
                                   b.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            else if(!s2.equals("")&&s1.equals(""){
                                   b.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            else {
                            b.setEnabled(true);
                          }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
  et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
                            String s2 = et2.getText().toString();

                            if(s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")){
                                   b.setEnabled(false);
                            } 
                            else if(!s1.equals("")&&s2.equals("")){
                                   b.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            else if(!s2.equals("")&&s1.equals(""){
                                   b.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            else {
                            b.setEnabled(true);
                          }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach a TextWatcher that is called whenever the text in one of the EditText fields is changed.

```
private EditText mName;
private EditText mPassword;
private Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_check);
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mName.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
    mPassword.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
}

private TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        boolean nameNotEmpty = mName.getText().length()>0;
        boolean pwNotEmpty = mPassword.getText().length()>0;
        mButton.setEnabled(nameNotEmpty && pwNotEmpty);
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private TextWatcher mPhoneNumberEtWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if (charSequence.length() >= 10) {
            mPhoneImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_activate));

            if (mPasswordEt.getText().toString().length() >= 5) {
                mLoginBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }

        } else {
            mPhoneImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone));
            mLoginBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
};

mPhoneNumberEt.addTextChangedListener(mPhoneNumberEtWatcher);
```

You should use TextWatcher. That will call method after typing of user. And you can check length and somthing else of your edit text.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  if(s1.equals("") && s2.equals(""))
    {
        b.setEnabled(true);
        // to change color of the button you need to apply style to the button[here refer custom bg][1]
    }
    else
    {
        b.setEnabled(false);
       //do nothing or display toast msg
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I only want to add that the check will **NOT** work if the `InputType` of the `EditText` is a password (or similar) and the fuction to proof the length of the text (see other answers) is called from

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {...}
```

So it is important to call the check from

```
@Override 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey if want to use the code cut the button needs to change color if the editText1_id and the editText1_passcode is in and in 4 digits

```
checkValidation();

    editText1_id.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
    editText1_passcode.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
}

private void checkValidation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1_id.getText()))
            || (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1_passcode.getText())))
        loginbtn.setEnabled(false);
    else
        loginbtn.setEnabled(true);

}


TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        checkValidation();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

}
```