# Displaying image in extream side of EditText android

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext

```
 <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/main_email_tv"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/lock"

                    />
```

I am adding lock image in edittext in the right side, but the problem is im not able to adjust image size in edittext.

Actually i was looking for this option and finally got that.
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pic
by this option a image can be displayed in extream left  of EditText.
for other who is looking for same kind of answer must make sure that the size of image should be around 25-35px or else image will not be displayed properly inside editetxt.

Comment: you want image in right of this edittext or in edittext right side ?

Comment: @amit Sir i want image inside edittext to the right side

Comment: that would not be possible you need to take other imagiview right of edittext

Comment: Yes it can be on the righthandside.left or anywhere but not inside!

Comment: Sir image is already coming inside edittext , the thing is adjustability. how to make it small like  width = 10sp and height= 10sp

Comment: is your issue solved@MehtabAlam

Comment: @ amit  Sir, Issue not solved but I got my answer, I have to get image of specified dimensions in order to use it inside the Edittext.

Answer (score 2):

set Your Image like this

```
                   <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                   >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_dob"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:hint="Date Of Birth"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_date"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />


                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002963/in-android-how-to-make-login-button-disable-with-respect-to-edittext      Sir, see image in this url, see the image left to the username and password , i want same like that just in right direction

Comment: you have two option . 

either  you have to take your image as your require height and width. or you can also follow above approach  . it will do same as you want

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of using `EditText` alone

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp">

    <EditText  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="How to select and crop image"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```