# How to make EditTexts mandatory in my Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android, Using a Registration form linked to a Firebase db.How do i make all the Edittext fields mandatory?

Using a few edit Text fields, submit button should either be not visible /not functional until all the fields are filled,and User should also be not created.

Here's the code segment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);
    //get data from previous activity
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String RegAmount=intent.getStringExtra("regAmount");
    String Ename=intent.getStringExtra("Ename");
    //data recieved
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputUsn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usn);
    inputEventName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EventName);
    inputEventName.setText(Ename);
    inputContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    inputCollege = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.college);
    inputRegAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegAmount);
    inputRegAmount.setText(RegAmount);
    SubmitForm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegButton);
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users");
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").setValue("Saviskara Registration Form");
    // app_title change listener
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "App title updated");

            String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            // update toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(appTitle);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error)
        {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
    // Save the user
    SubmitForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String usn=inputUsn.getText().toString();
            String eventName=inputEventName.getText().toString();
            String contact=inputContact.getText().toString();
            String college =inputCollege.getText().toString();
            String regamount=inputRegAmount.getText().toString();
            createUser(name,email,usn,contact,regamount,eventName,college);
            Toast.makeText(Firebase.this,"Thank You!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(Firebase.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
private void createUser(String name, String email,String usn,String pno,String regamount,String ename,String colName)
{
    // TODO

    userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

    User user = new User(name,email,usn,pno,regamount,ename,colName);

    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);

    addUserChangeListener();

}
private void addUserChangeListener()
{
    // User data change listener
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // Check for null
            if (user == null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }

            // clear edit text
            inputEmail.setText("");
            inputName.setText("");
            inputCollege.setText("");
            inputContact.setText("");
            inputRegAmount.setText("");
            inputUsn.setText("");
            inputEventName.setText("");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });



}
}
```

Can I add a payment gateway via *InstaMojo* to the same and push into FireBase DB only when the payment is successful?

Also couldn't find anywhere the InstaMojo guide for firebase, just java python and php.

Does it mean I need a new backend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check validation like this for `EditText`:

```
SubmitForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                if(checkValidation()) {
                    String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String usn = inputUsn.getText().toString().trim();
                    String eventName = inputEventName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String contact = inputContact.getText().toString().trim();
                    String college = inputCollege.getText().toString().trim();
                    String regamount = inputRegAmount.getText().toString().trim();
                    createUser(name, email, usn, contact, regamount, eventName, college);
                    Toast.makeText(Firebase.this, "Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Firebase.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

and `checkValidation` method will be:

```
  public  boolean checkValidation() {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String usn = inputUsn.getText().toString().trim();
        String eventName = inputEventName.getText().toString().trim();
        String contact = inputContact.getText().toString().trim();
        String college = inputCollege.getText().toString().trim();
        String regamount = inputRegAmount.getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.length() <= 0) {
            inputName.requestFocus();
            inputName.setError("Enter Name");
            return false;
        } else if (email.length() <= 0) {
            inputEmail.requestFocus();
            inputEmail.setError("Enter Email");
            return false;

        } else if (usn.length() <= 0) {
            inputUsn.requestFocus();
            inputUsn.setError("Enter USN");
            return false;

        } else if (eventName.length() <= 0) {
            inputEventName.requestFocus();
            inputEventName.setError("Enter EventName");
            return false;

        } else if (contact.length() <= 0) {
            inputContact.requestFocus();
            inputContact.setError("Enter Contact");
            return false;

        } else if (college.length() <= 0) {
            inputCollege.requestFocus();
            inputCollege.setError("Enter Collage");
            return false;

        } else if (regamount.length() <= 0) {
            inputRegAmount.requestFocus();
            inputRegAmount.setError("Enter RegAmount");
            return false;

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

for submit button visibility, you can use `TextWatcher` with all `EditText` field.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question - **Button should either be not visible/not functional until all the fields are filled**:

You need to implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to check for input change in EditText ([Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002963/in-android-how-to-make-login-button-disable-with-respect-to-edittext)) or use `OnTextChanged()` using [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) ([Example 2](https://dxungngh.com/2016/05/11/ontextchanged-with-butterknife/)).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a view below every edit text and can check if edit text is empty or not in a handler every 1500 ms  and show view if it fulfill condition.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        if(edittext1.isEmpty()){
view1.setvisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
}
else if(edittext2.isEmpty()){
view2.setvisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
}
and so on


        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Comment: too bad idea. why we need this for continuous running handler. we can use TextWatcher as well.