# In Xamarin.Android, how to make Login button disable with respect to EditText?

Tags: c#, android, authentication, xamarin, button

I'm looking how to make [this funcionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002963/in-android-how-to-make-login-button-disable-with-respect-to-edittext) on C# to Android Xamarin. It is to enable the login buttom only when the user type his user name and password. Other wise, the button shuold be disable.

My C# code doesn't work

```
            String edit_user_001 = (String) FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.id_edit_user_001);
            String edit_password_001 = (String) FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.id_edit_password_001);
            Button btn_login_001 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.id_btn_login_001);

            if (edit_user_001.Equals("") || edit_user_001.Equals("")){
                btn_login_001.Enabled = false;
            } else {
                User user = new User(edit_user_001, edit_user_001);
                btn_login_001.Enabled = true;
                btn_login_001.Click += (sender, e) => {
                    login(user);
                };
            }
```

Someone knows what I am doing wron?

Comment: why are you casting your controls to string?  That will return a null.

Comment: I need them to be a string

Comment: an `EditText` control is a UI element.  It has a **string** property containing the user's text, but you cannot **cast it** to a string.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to cast your `EditText` controls to `string` which will not work

```
String edit_user_001 = (String) FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.id_edit_user_001);
```

instead

```
EditText edit_user_001 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.id_edit_user_001);
```

then use it's `Text` property to access the string value

```
if (edit_user_001.Text.Equals("") || edit_user_001.Text.Equals(""))
```

Comment: If I do that, the button still disabled although I type into both inputs

Comment: where is this code located?  If you only execute it when the page loads and the inputs are empty, of course nothing will happen.  You need to execute it when the user enters text using the `KeyPress` event

Comment: It is located onCreate. Should I change to another function?

Comment: yes, read my last comment about using `KeyPress`

Comment: I'm looking for an example but I can't find an understable one (I'm Android noob). Would you mind to post one example of the KeyPress?

Comment: search "xamarin edittext" and the first hit is a link to the official docs, which contains an example of using `KeyPress`.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/edit-text

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for "KeyPress Xamarin".